# How do I counter-block the spinning Gasfellas?

Tags: bastion

Some of the Gasfellas (I believe it's the higher-level, boss-type guys) spin around and around and do quite a bit of damage if the Kid gets caught in their attack.

I realise they're best dealt with from a distance, but that luxury is not always available. Is it possible to counter-block them (I presume on the first spin) and I've just not been able to do it yet, or is it an uncounterblocklable (phew) attack?

Comment: I bounced into the exact same problem, but it seemed impossible to me to counter-block them, even during the first spin...  You can easily train your counter-block against them in the Kid's dream; but I'm really not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***EDIT***: It turned out that I was wrong about the player being able to succesfully counter-blocking a spinning gas-fella, and as promised here is a video of me trying to prove it:

I try with standard blocking and the Mirror Shield secret skill, neither one successful.

<strike>It is possible to counterblock them though it is quite difficult. All you have to do is wait for them to get really close to you and hit block right before they hit. This is really difficult though so I would recommend that you just evade them and use ranged weapons to defeat them.</strike>

Comment: Don't suppose you have a video showing this, do you? Haven't managed to find one...

Comment: @Alex I can try to record it when I get home :)

Comment: Well it seems I have 23 hours to award the bounty, so if you can provide a video you can have the 50 rep. That's 36% of what you have already! :D

Comment: Video evidence + using even the Mirror Shield - definitely seems like you can't counter-block them.